# Getting error with a jscript datatable in C#. New to jscript

Tags: c#, web, razor-pages, jscript-10

I am new to jscript and am changing the code in a C# razor page. the data model have the variable AgvId in the model, but when I try and use it in the datatable column I get the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhBvs.png)
I think the name is not correct, but do not understand how to find what the correct name is to use. I hope someone with more experience can give me some help.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
 var table = $('#orders').DataTable({
            "processing": false, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": false, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "lengthMenu": [[20, 50, -1], [20, 50, "All"]],
            "pagingType": "simple",
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Orders/OrderList/data", // for client side /LoadDataAll
                "type": "GET",                   // for client side "GET"
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "select": 'single',
            "columns": [
                { "data": "created", "render": DateRenderer, "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "wmsid", "name": "WMSID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "index", "name": "OrderID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "pick.name", "name": "Pick", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "drop.name", "name": "Drop", "autoWidth": true },
                //{ "data": "sequence", "name": "Sequence", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "agvid", "name": "AgvID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "status", "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true },
                //{ "data": "priority", "name": "Priority", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "null", "render": ModifyRenderer, "orderable": false },
                { "data": "null", "render": CancelRenderer, "orderable": false },
                //{ "data": "null", "render": DeleteRenderer, "orderable": false },
            ]
        });
```

Here is the web page table for the web page

```
<table width="99%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="99%">
                <input id="orderidcurrent" name="orderidcurrenthidden" value="0" hidden />
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <table id="orders" class="display">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="text-condensed">
                                <th>Created</th>
                                <th>ID WMS</th>
                                <th>ID SM</th>
                                <th>Pick</th>
                                <th>Drop</th>
                                @*<th>Sequence</th>*@
                                <th>AGVID</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                @*<th>Priority</th>*@
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th> @*add back in if using buttons, TAF, 11/21/22*@
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have added the OnGet method for additional information.

```
public JsonResult OnGet(string strRouteText, string orderid,string pick = null, String drop = null)
    {
        if (OnPostActive)
        {
            ShowStartButton = false;
            _OnPostOneShot = true;

        }
        else
        {
            ShowStartButton = true;
            if (_OnPostOneShot == true)
            {
                //Redirect("/Orders/OrderList/");
                _OnPostOneShot = false;
            }
        }



        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strRouteText))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (strRouteText == "data")
        {
            return LoadData();
        }
        else if (strRouteText.StartsWith("conn"))
        {
            IpcControlStatus objIpcControlStatus = _infAgvSystem.GetStatus();
            bool bConnected = _infAgvSystem.Connected;

            if (bConnected)
            {
                return new JsonResult("true");
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonResult("false");
            }
        }
        else if (strRouteText.StartsWith("ids"))
        {
            List<Order> listOrders = _infAgvSystem.GetOrders();

            List<string> listIDs = new List<string>();
            foreach (Order objOrder in listOrders)
            {
                listIDs.Add(objOrder.WMSID);
            }

            return new JsonResult(listIDs.ToList());
        }
        else if (strRouteText.StartsWith("picks"))
        {
            List<Station> listStations = _infAgvSystem.GetStations();
            List<Station> listPickStations = listStations.FindAll(x => (x.Type == "P") || (x.Type == "B"));

            List<string> listPicks = new List<string>();
            foreach (Station objStation in listPickStations)
            {
                listPicks.Add(objStation.Name);
            }
            PickList = listPicks;
            

            return new JsonResult(listPicks.ToList());
        }
        else if (strRouteText.StartsWith("drops"))
        {
            List<Station> listStations = _infAgvSystem.GetStations();
            List<Station> listDropStations = listStations.FindAll(x => (x.Type == "D") || (x.Type == "B"));

            List<string> listDrops = new List<string>();
            foreach (Station objStation in listDropStations)
            {
                listDrops.Add(objStation.Name);
            }
            DropList = listDrops;

            return new JsonResult(listDrops.ToList());
        }
        else if (strRouteText.StartsWith("priorities"))
        {
            List<AACPriority> listAACPriority = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AACPriority)).Cast<AACPriority>().ToList();

            List<string> listPriorities = new List<string>();

            foreach(AACPriority eAACPriority in listAACPriority)
            {
                if (!listPriorities.Contains(eAACPriority.ToString()))
                    listPriorities.Add(eAACPriority.ToString());
            }

            return new JsonResult(listPriorities.ToList());
        }
        else if (strRouteText.StartsWith("order"))
        {
            List<Order> listOrders = _infAgvSystem.GetOrders();

            Order objOrder = listOrders.Find(x => x.WMSID == orderid);

            if (objOrder != null)
            {
                AACPriority eAACPriority;
                if (Enum.TryParse<AACPriority>(Convert.ToString(objOrder.Priority), out AACPriority eTryAACPriority))
                {
                    eAACPriority = eTryAACPriority;
                }
                else
                {
                    eAACPriority = AACPriority.LOWEST;
                }
                WebDisplayOrder onjWebDisplayOrder = new WebDisplayOrder(objOrder.State, objOrder.Index, objOrder.WMSID, objOrder.Pick, objOrder.Drop, objOrder.AgvID, objOrder.Status, objOrder.Sequence, eAACPriority);
                JsonResult objJsonResult = new JsonResult(onjWebDisplayOrder);
                return objJsonResult;
            }
           
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d4eR.png)

I have tried many different names and cases, but do not know how to determine the name needed or how to add it if that I needed.

Comment: Looks like you don't have a column named AGVID in the dataset returned by the ajax call

Comment: Steve - How can I determine the columns being sent or add to the columns from the Ajax call? I added the OnGet method above and it looks like the AgvId is in the object returned as a json. I am obviously missing something.

Comment: Try to add one column at the time until you run into the one column that is causing the issue.

Comment: The issue is that I do not know what the correct name should be, I do not see the column names that work setup in the code as I would expect.  under 'columns":[ {"data": "status" works, but status does not show up for the table column name that I can find.